# libjpeg-turbo - whats the difference between libturbojpeg.a and libjpeg.a

Tags: libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

My intent is to use libjpeg-turbo ( see http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/Main/HomePage ) as a drop in replacement for the common libjpeg (version 6) from Independent Jpeg Group (http://www.ijg.org/). 
My development platform is Linux on X_86 , 64 bit

I downloaded the "official" binary packages from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/1.3.1/

there are two static libraries supplied "libturbojpeg.a" and "libjpeg.a" and both of them seem to support traditional libjpeg API.

I suppose the "libturbojpeg.a" is the "faster" implementation and that's the one I should use .. but wanted to be sure about that. Also have been wondering why is the "libjpeg.a" packaged with this version if no one might want to use it ?

After browsing through most of the documentation I am yet not sure

I tried crude methods like

- using  Linux "nm" command to list symbol - 
  Both these libraries have same symbols in them so I could use them interchangeably
- using linux archiver "ar -tvf" to peep into libraries and check object names - The objects in them have similar names except that the ones in libturbojpeg.a have a prefix "libturbojpeg_la-j"

Any insights ?

Thanks - Yogesh Devi

Answer (score 1):

Looks like - libjpeg.a supports the regular libjpeg API and the libturbojpeg.a supports the TurboJPEG API which sspposidly "simpler to use".